# Why do I lose bootstrap styling when passing variables through URL in Flask?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2

When I pass a variable in Flask my Bootstrap styling doesn't work. If I use a normal app route without the variable the styling works.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
app.py:

@app.route('/edit_customer/<c_id>')
def edit_customer(c_id):
    #customer = queries.get_customer(c_id)
    return render_template('edit_customer.html')
```

My base template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <link href="static/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        {% block head %}
        {% endblock %}

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="sb-topnav navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <!-- Navbar Brand-->
            <a class="navbar-brand ps-3" href="index.html">Company Admin Portal</a>
            <!-- Sidebar Toggle-->
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm order-1 order-lg-0 me-4 me-lg-0" id="sidebarToggle" href="#!"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
            <!-- Navbar Search-->
            <form class="d-none d-md-inline-block form-inline ms-auto me-0 me-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search for..." aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" />
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnNavbarSearch" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- Navbar-->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto ms-md-0 me-3 me-lg-4">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-user fa-fw"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Activity Log</a></li>
                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="layoutSidenav">
            <div id="layoutSidenav_nav">
                <nav class="sb-sidenav accordion sb-sidenav-dark" id="sidenavAccordion">
                    <div class="sb-sidenav-menu">
                        <div class="nav">
                            <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Core</div>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></div>
                                Dashboard
                            </a>
                            
                            <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">INTERFACE</div>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/customers">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-table"></i></div>
                                Customers
                            </a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/bids">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-table"></i></div>
                                Bids
                            </a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/workorders">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-table"></i></div>
                                Work Orders
                            </a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="invoices">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-table"></i></div>
                                Invoices
                            </a>
                            {%if session['email'] == 'test@example.net'%}
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/admin">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-table"></i></div>
                                Admin
                            </a>
                            {%endif%}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sb-sidenav-footer">
                        <div class="small">Logged in as:</div>
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
                <main>
                    <div class="container-fluid px-4">
                        {% block content %}

                        {% endblock %}
                    </div>
                </main>
                <footer class="py-4 bg-light mt-auto">
                    <div class="container-fluid px-4">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between small">
                            <div class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; Company 2021</div>
                            <div>
                                <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                                &middot;
                                <a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The edit_customer page that loses the styling:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
  <title>Test | Test</title>
    {{ super() }}
    <style type="text/css">
        .important { color: #336699; }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Edit Customers</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including your styles.css with a dynamic route like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
```

Answer (score -1):

1. How are you making the call to the backend (your server)? You should post the code
2. You don't actually need the section below in your edit_customer page because it already exists in base.html which you are extending

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

Comment: I  called the backend with the app.route app.py . It's the first section of code that I included.